# How can I enable SwiftUI preview content in my app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I create new project with SwiftUI as User Interface I can be able to see preview next to my SwiftUI class but when I add SwiftUI class on an existing project (its User Interface is storyboard) SwiftUI can be imported and no issue to use it but preview is not shown automatically when I open the SwiftUI class.

The newly created project with SwiftUI:

[image: The newly created project with SwiftUI:]

Already exixsting project with no preview:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the left most item and check canvas

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works. I thought I need to enable something on project settings but it was easier.